# Powershell: system-diagnostics-processstartinfo hangs, reason unknown

Tags: powershell, processstartinfo

Highly influenced by other questions here on Stackoverflow I have ended up with this method for starting processes from my Powershell-scripts

```
function global:system-diagnostics-processstartinfo {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='Low')]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage='Full path to exectuable')]
    [Alias('exectuable')]
    [string]$exe,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage='All arguments to be sent to exectuable')]
    [Alias('args')]
    [string]$arguments
)

if (!(Test-Path $exe)) {
    $log.errorFormat("Did not find exectuable={0}, aborting script", $exe)
    exit 1  
}

$log.infoFormat("Start exectuable={0} with arguments='{1}'", $exe, $arguments)
$processStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo($exe)
$processStartInfo.FileName = $exe
$processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$processStartInfo.Arguments = $arguments
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $processStartInfo
$log.info("Start exectuable and wait for exit")
$p.Start() | Out-Null

#$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$log.infoFormat("exectuable={0}  stdout: {1}", $exe, $stdout)
$log.debugFormat("exectuable={0} stderr: {1}",  $exe,$stderr)
$global:ExitCode = $p.ExitCode
$log.debugFormat("exectuable={0} Exitcode: {1}", $exe, $p.ExitCode)

return $stdout
}
```

Pretty straight forward with some added logging etc. And it works in all my current use cases execpt one. I have created a script that copies the database dump for our production instance of Confluence to our test server. Then it uses the above method to drop existing database, all fine. But the actual restore just hangs for ever and ever. So right now I have to exit the script and then run the following command manually

```
d:\postgresql\bin\pg_restore.exe -U postgres -d confluencedb -v -1 d:\temp\latest-backup.pgdump
```

It takes some time and there is quite a lot of output. Which makes me belive that there must be either one the following causing the issue

- The amount of output makes a buffer overflow and stalls the script
- It takes to much time

Anyone with similar experiences who can help me resolve this. It would enable to schedule the import, not having to do it manually as today.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following right after process. Start:

```
# Capture output during process execution so we don't hang
# if there is too much output.
do
{
    if (!$process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        [void]$StdOut.AppendLine($process.StandardOutput.ReadLine())
    }
    if (!$process.StandardError.EndOfStream)
    {
        [void]$StdErr.AppendLine($process.StandardError.ReadLine())
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
}
while (!$process.HasExited)
        
# Capture any standard output generated between our last poll and process end.
while (!$process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    [void]$StdOut.AppendLine($process.StandardOutput.ReadLine())
}
    
# Capture any error output generated between our last poll and process end.
while (!$process.StandardError.EndOfStream)
{
    [void]$StdErr.AppendLine($process.StandardError.ReadLine())
}

# Wait for the process to exit.
$process.WaitForExit()
LogWriteFunc ("END process: " + $ProcessName)

if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0)
{
    LogWriteFunc ("Error: Script execution failed: " + $process.ExitCode )
    $FuncResult = 1
}

# Log and display any standard output.
if ($StdOut.Length -gt 0)
{
    LogWriteFunc ($StdOut.ToString())
}
    
# Log and display any error output.
if ($StdErr.Length -gt 0)
{
    LogWriteFunc ($StdErr.ToString())
}
```